# Grails one-to-many - mapping cascade

Tags: hibernate, grails, relational-database

Here is my situation:

A relation 1-N between a class called League and one called Team.

One league can have multiple teams.
In unit test I tried to assign: team A to a league 1 and than the same team A to a league 2.

What happen is that both leagues refer to the same team A. But the team A only to league 2.

What is the best way to delete the reference of league 1 to team A ?

**EDIT:**

```
class League {

    static hasMany = [ teams: Team, schedules: Schedule ]

    String name
    ...
}


class Team {
    static belongsTo = [ league: League ]
    ...
}
```

LeagueTest

```
def league1 = new League( name: "Serie A" )
def league2 = new League( name: "Premier League" )

def team = new Team( name: 'AC Milan', stadium: 'San siro', nation: 'Italy' )

league1.addToTeams( team )
assert league1.numOfTeams() > league2.numOfTeams() //true

league2.addToTeams( team )
assert league1.numOfTeams() == league2.numOfTeams() //true

assert team.league == league2 //true
assert team.league == league1 //false
```

Comment: How does the relation look in you domain-class? (belongsTo, hasMany is what I'm referring to)

Comment: Please show your code. Why do you assign a Team to both Leagues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of persistence always belongs to the owning domain class.

In your case, the League class is responsible for persistence, ie, it is the owning class. Therefore, to remove the reference of league 1 to team A you will need to call the appropriate method on the league object. In your case this will become:

league1.removeFromTeams(team) //team is the Team object which needs to be removed from 
                              //the required league

Comment: i hope you know that owning class is the one that is assigned with static belongsTo, in your case it is league